# Checking that PYTHONIOENCODING is always "utf8"

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I know unittests and use write them daily.

They get executed during development and CI.

Now I have test which I would like to ensure on the production system:

> PYTHONIOENCODING must be "utf8"

Above I used the verb "test", this means I want to check the state. This question is not about how to do this.

AFAIK the unittest framework can't help me here, since it only gets executed during development and CI.

How to solve this in the python world withou re-inventing the wheel?

Above is only an example. There are several other things next to PYTHONIOENCODING which I would like to check.

Next use case for these checks: Some days ago we had an issue on the production sever. The command-line tool `convert` gets used and some versions are broken and create wrong results. I would like to write a simple check to ensure that the convert tool on the production server is not broken.

Comment: I would use an assert near the entry point of the program.

Comment: @rfkortekaas  I updated the question. There are several other things which I want to check in the production environment. I am afraid that doing several  assertions on every program start could slow it down.

Comment: @guettli No worries. These checks only takes minimal time and it shouldn't be a performance impact.

Comment: @iBug I added a new thing which I would like to be sure, that it is the way I want it. This check would take some seconds.

Comment: It looks like you're after infrastructure tests; we use [`pytest-testinfra`](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest) for that. Tests are stored as a separate project in a separate repository and are invoked from CI server once the container images are built; we deploy built containers in an isolated production test env and run the tests against them.

Comment: @hoefling please write your comment as answer, then I am able to up-vote it.

Comment: Option 1: protect what needs protection -- i.e. validate environment before call to command-line `convert`, at which point you mighst as well wrap it in bash script.

Comment: Option 2: force whatever environment you need in `site.py` -- note it's tricky to do right, because module is normally only imported once. But it can be done and was commonly done in Python2.

Comment: Option 3: Upgrade to Python 3.7 where UTF-8 is the default encoding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `testinfra`

If you want to write and run tests against the deployment infrastructure, you can use the [`testinfra`](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest) plugin for `pytest`. For example, test for a simple requirement of validating an environment variable on target machine could look like:

```
def test_env_var(host):
    assert host.run_expect((0,), 'test "$PYTHONIOENCODING" == "utf8"')
```

This infrastructure test suite can be developed in a separate project and invoked before the actual deployment takes place (for example, we invoke the infra tests right after the docker image is built; if the tests fail, the image is not uploaded to our private image repository/deployed to prod etc).

Comment: Yes, this answer sound good. Unfortunately this makes my question a question about a tool. I hope the stackoverflow police does not catch us.

Comment: No worries, there are so many `pytest` plugins, you can't remember them all anyway. Also, maybe someone will provide a better answer now that the question is featured.

Answer (score 3):

#### Straightforward approach (Checking)

Put this near the start of the code:

```
import os

if os.environ.get('PYTHONIOENCODING', '').lower() not in {'utf-8', 'utf8'}:
    raise EnvironmentError("Environment variable $PYTHONIOENCODING must be set to 'utf8'")
```

---

#### Alternative solution (Ensuring)

In one of the projects I code for, there's a "startup script", so instead of running `python3 main.py`, we run this in production:

```
bash main.sh
```

whose content is rather simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

exec /usr/bin/env python3 main.py
```

Comment: `export` should be on a separate line if you really need this to be `/bin/sh`. The `export variable=value` syntax extension is supported by `ksh` and `bash` and some others, but not (portably) by `sh`.  The portable way to write this is `variable=value; export variable`

Comment: @tripleee but it's been working for years on Ubuntu (dash).

Comment: All I'm saying it isn't strictly portable. You can find environments where `puke` is a valid command, too.

Comment: @tripleee I picked the easier choice: the shebang line is changed.

Comment: @iBug I am sorry. This question is about checking the final state, not about creating this state. I updated the question.

Comment: @guettli I've also updated my answer. The first section describes a way to *check* it without modifying anything.